# Good way for using html5 tags

Tags: html

I try to use the HTML5 standard for my website.

Here I have a detail page of my blog.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<article>
    <hgroup class="title">
        <h1>@Model.Title</h1>
        <h6>@Html.InsertHeaderPost(@Model.PublishDate, @Model.Tags)</h6>
    </hgroup>
    <p>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Content)</p>
</article>
```

**First question:** is it the good way when using article and hgroup tag?

**Second question:** How can I reduce the space between Intruction à ... and Tags: .. ? I didn't succeed.

Here is my css for hgroup

```
/* page titles */ 
hgroup.title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: For reduce simply change the margin-bottom

Comment: @Hadas: I try setting margin and padding to 0 but I still have spaces between these two lines and I don't know why?

Comment: try 'hgroup.title h6{margin-top:-10px;}'

Comment: Are you trying to reduce the space between the h1 and h6?  If so, try setting the css on the h1 and h6 rather than the hgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is fine. As for the margin, try using a browser developer tool such as Firebug or Chrome's built-in one (press F12) to see where the space is coming from. Right-clicking and selecting "Inspect" on the elements should show their margins/padding.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I do with F12 (IE) but I didn't see any spaces... when I set margins and padding to 0 I still have spaces between these two lines.

Comment: Even when you explicitly give `h1` and `h6` margins and paddings of 0? i.e. `h1,h6{padding:0;margin:0;}`? Unless `h1` has a height set I can't think of what else it might be.

Comment: The browser debugger will be able to show any other rules on that element that may be causing problems, so you might want to check it over (in one other than IE or Opera's, which are both stripped clones of Chrome/Firebug).